# Using a GET request in Volley debugging with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I am new to kotlin / android development, I have been following the google / android docs with using Volley to send requests....Still have not go to handling JSON yet.

When I put the example `GET` in a function in kotlin using android development studio, I am getting the error message from `ErrorListener`

```
    val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textReturn)
    val url = "http://wwww.google.com"
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

    val stringRequest =
        StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, Response.Listener<String> { response ->

            var strRes = response.toString()
            textView.text = strRes

        }, Response.ErrorListener {textView.text = "That didn't work!"})

    queue.add(stringRequest)
}
```

I am unsure on how to debug and come from a very javascript / php background where console.log() or print() will post to the console, kotlin does not seem to have such a simple function for this.

Comment: In kotlin for console log error you can use 'Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                    VolleyLog.e(TAG, "/post request fail! Error: ${error.message}")
                    completionHandler(null)
                }'

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly certain about Volley, but eg. with Retrofit, the error listener will only be triggered on hard errors - but common HTTP status codes, besides `200 OK`, end up in the response listener. Retrofit with GsonConverter and ORM is the most common combo for converting JSON to POJO (one can define a whole API as a web-service and it converts the JSON automatically). However, when still learning Java/Kotlin, it might not hurt to use Volley and not use ORM auto-mapping (because all the nuts & bolts are being abstracted away). PHP background is useful for whatever API interaction.

And concerning the actual question, in Kotlin one can log with: [`println`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/println.html) and Android Studio can be used for the actual [debugging](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) (it provides similar functionality alike `F12` tools and `xdebug` provide). Using logging to debug is only partially applicable, eg. when wanting to let the console tell the story of what happened - otherwise, just use break-points, watches or evaluate expressions.